# How to check/rectify the LaTeX file mode (UTF-8 or ANSII)

Tags: editors

When I will open the text file in the `notepad` the file was like:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}%\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,float]{revtex4-1}\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}\usepackage{color}\usepackage{hyperref}\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}%\usepackage{multicol}%\usepackage[showframe]  
{geometry}\usepackage{graphicx}%\usepackage{indentfirst}% usepackage[a4paper,inner=1.4cm,outer=1.8cm,top=1.4cm,bottom=0.5cm,pdftex]{geometry}\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathitbf}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}\renewcommand{\th}{^{\mbox{\tiny th}}}\renewcommand{\=}{\!=\!}\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1|}\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\langle #1|#2\rangle}\newcommand{\rv}{\mathitbf r}\newcommand{\sv}{\mathitbf s}\newcommand{\calBold}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath
```

When I was open in any other editor in for eg.: `epsilon|notepad++` the file seems like:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
%\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,float]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

%\usepackage{multicol}

%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}

%\usepackage[a4paper,inner=1.4cm,outer=1.8cm,top=1.4cm,bottom=0.5cm,pdftex]{geometry}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathitbf}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}

\renewcommand{\th}{^{\mbox{\tiny th}}}
\renewcommand{\=}{\!=\!}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1|}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\langle #1|#2\rangle}
\newcommand{\rv}{\mathitbf r}
\newcommand{\sv}{\mathitbf s}
\newcommand{\calBold}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath${\cal #1}$}}
```

I don't know what is the issues. Could some one help me to find the issues?

Comment: this question doesn't seem related to biblatex or tex-core tags? Also it seems unrelated to UTF-8 file encoding, Are you just asking why notepad loses the ends of lines? It is a very primitive editor and only accepts msdos not linux line ends, it doesn't matter to tex though, you can still edit the file.

Comment: unrelated but your definitions seem strange `\cal` is latex 2.09 syntax for documents written before 1993 `\mathcal{#1}` would be more usual, and you load `bm` package but don't use it why not `\bm{r}` rather than the low level math alphabet declaration?

Comment: If you open the file in Notepad++ you can see the line endings that your file has in the bottom status bar. If it does not say "Windows (CR LF)" (it could for example say "Linux (LF)") then Windows' Notepad editor will have trouble displaying that file. You can see the line ends explicitly by going to "View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters" or "EOL characters". You can change the line ends in Notepad++ with "Edit > EOL Conversion".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How to move this question to `Stackoverflow->perl`

Comment: Questions can only be moved to meta.TeX.SX via the normal path, everything else requires moderator attention. You can flag your own question. Or you can simply delete your question and re-ask manually. Why do you think Perl would be more appropriate here, though?

Comment: Yes. I need to identify the mode in Perl before starting the conversion.

Comment: Mhhh, I still don't understand where Perl enters the equation here. What you have shown us so far is a simple TeX document. Is that somehow automatically generated by Perl? Did you check the EOL characters with Notepad++?

Comment: No we have simple conversion tool in Perl language but the tool doesn't recognized the text line by line. Instead of EOL characters issue the file fully merged without `enters`.